# How can I access all the characters on a Chromebook keyboard?

Tags: google-chrome-os, chromebook

I can't seem to be able to access the blue characters on my Chromebook keyboard.

Technical info about the Chromebook I am using:

Google Chrome   121.0.6167.9 (Official Build) dev (64-bit)
Revision    9a74004e5ee81bd2e17f315d14be3089b0d40be0-refs/branch-heads/6167@{#55}
Platform    15699.5.0 (Official Build) dev-channel grunt
Firmware Version    Google_Grunt.11031.169.0
Customization ID    careena
ARC 11153516 SDK Version: 30
JavaScript  V8 12.1.285.2
User Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (X11; CrOS x86_64 14541.0.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36

I've tried all kinds of Ctrl, Alt, Alt gr and Shift combinations but I can't access them.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Does that mean your program can't get a certain key?

Comment: @NorioYamamoto Yes, and I also can't type them in a text field.

Comment: What exactly are the blue characters?
All keys on my Chromebook are black.

Comment: @NorioYamamoto You can see the blue characters on [this image](https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/qM4AAOSwHU9dnzjH/s-l1200.webp) of my Chromebook's keyboard